# Infopath 2010 to infopath 2013 all information get to other site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, infopath, infopath2010

I do have one sharepoint site name ABC.. 
in ABC there are infopath 2010 and sharepoint 2010 technology.

How to get all those forms into infopath 2013 and Sharepoint 2013 technology site XYZ??

I have 2000 employee information in ABC.. want all of them in XYZ.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Pls refer this. Hope this will help.

https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2013/03/infopath-and-sharepoint-2013-upgrading-your-forms/

Comment: But i need more help of yours... i want all the list data in to SITE XYZ from ABC too. where ABC contain data with infopath and want to migrate it at XYZ site's list also contain item connected to infopath. how can i do that.?? PLease Help.